# How to get the position of a character in Python and store it in a variable?

Tags: python, string, function, variables, position

I am looking for a way to store the position integer of a character into a variable, but now I'm using a way I used in Delphi 2010, which is not right, according to Jupyter Notebook

This is my code I have this far:

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    for index in text:
        if index==' ':
            if text[0] == text[pos(index)+1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            pass
```

The aim, is to get two words (word + space + word) and if the beginning letters, of both words, match, then it has to show True, otherwise it shows False

Comment: you jsut want `my_string.index(character)`, e.g. `'hello, world'.index(' ')`

Comment: *but* it seems like you want to loop over the items and index over `text`, for that, just do `for i, c in enumerate(text): ...`

Comment: But, It hink you just want `word1, word2 = text.split(); return word1[0] == word2[0]`

Answer (score 1):

For getting the index of a letter in a string (as the title asks), just use `str.index()`, or `str.find()` if you don't want an error to be raised if the letter/substring could not be found:

```
>>> text = 'seal sheep'
>>> text.index(' ')
4
```

However for your program, you do not need to use `str.index` if you want to identify the first and second word. Instead, use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to break up a given text into a list of substrings:

```
>>> words = text.split()  # With no arguments, splits words by whitespace
>>> words
['seal', 'sheep']
```

Then, you can take the letter of the first word and check if the second word begins with the same letter:

```
# For readability, you can assign the two words into their own variables
>>> first_word, second_word = words[0], words[1]
>>> first_word[0] == second_word[0]
True
```

Combined into a function, it may look like this:

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    words = text.split()
    first_word, second_word = words[0], words[1]

    return first_word[0] == second_word[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that text is a single line containing two words:

```
def animal_crackers(text):
   words = text.split()
   if len(words)== 1:
      break # we only have one word!
   # here, the .lower() is only necessary is the program is NOT case-sensitive
   # if you do care about the case of the letter, remove them
   if word[0].lower() == words[1][0].lower():
         return True
   else:
         return false
```